# Shape drawing program returning blank screen

Tags: c#

I'm using a namespace that I don' think many of you would be unfamilier with (SwinGameSDK), but my program isn't working as intended. It isn't producing a shape at the Mouse X and Mouse Y when clicked. Despite the unusual namespace I was wondering if there are any logical errors in my code that are preventing it from working? Im currently receive a warning that states: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." This is in relation to the _clr object.

I have tried following the instructions set by my teacher, but I clearly have something wrong

Class1.cs

```
namespace MyGame.src
{
    public class Shape
    {
        private Color _clr;
        public Color Color
        {
            get { return _clr; }
            set { _clr = Color.Green; } - ***This isn't working
        }

        private float _x,y
        public float x.....
        etc


        public void Draw()
        {
            SwinGame.FillRectangle(_clr, _x, _y, _width, _height);
        }

        public static bool PointInRect(Point2D pt, float x, float y, float w, float h)
        {
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

GameMain.cs

```
namespace MyGame
{
    public class GameMain
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Shape myShape = new Shape();
            //Open the game window
            SwinGame.OpenGraphicsWindow("GameMain", 800, 600);
            SwinGame.ShowSwinGameSplashScreen();

            //Run the game loop
            while(false == SwinGame.WindowCloseRequested())
            {
                //Fetch the next batch of UI interaction
                SwinGame.ProcessEvents();

                //Clear the screen and draw the framerate
                SwinGame.ClearScreen(Color.White);
                myShape.Draw();
                if (SwinGame.MouseClicked(MouseButton.LeftButton))
                {
                    myShape.X = SwinGame.MouseX();
                    myShape.Y = SwinGame.MouseY();
                }
                SwinGame.DrawFramerate(0,0);

                //Draw onto the screen
                SwinGame.RefreshScreen(60);   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I should be seeing a green square being drawn when I press the left button but nothing happens.
Thank you for any help you can give.

Comment: "set { _clr = value; } " and then "SwinGame.FillRectangle(Color.Green, _x, _y, _width, _height);" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

_clr is not initialised.
Change

```
public Color Color
        {
            get { return _clr; }
            set { _clr = Color.Green; } //***This isn't working
        }
```

to

```
public Color Color
        {
            get { return _clr; }
            set { _clr = value; } 
        }
```

and

```
SwinGame.FillRectangle(_clr, _x, _y, _width, _height);
```

to

```
 SwinGame.FillRectangle(this.Color, _x, _y, _width, _height);
```

Then in main method :

```
            SwinGame.ClearScreen(Color.White);

            if (SwinGame.MouseClicked(MouseButton.LeftButton))
            {
                myShape.X = SwinGame.MouseX();
                myShape.Y = SwinGame.MouseY();
                myShape.Color = Color.Green;
                myShape.Width = 10;
                myShape.Height = 10;
                myShape.Draw();
            }
```

You were trying to send null value (non initialised color) as parameter, and draw shape before setting color, size, location.

Comment: That's fixed the warning, but it still isn't producing a shape. Thank you for your help though

Comment: There's no code in sample that shows how you're drawing shape. Or adding it to screen. e.g. SwinGame.Add(myShape); ?

Comment: myShape.draw should be drawing the shape

Comment: Yep that did it. Thank you so much

Comment: no problem. you can change this.Color to _clr - my previous edit was not taking OO principles into account.